# Nested List of Dictionaries in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas, nested

[image]

Here the nutrients column had 4 dictionaries in a list, each dictionary has 5 keys with 1 values on each key.

How can I flatten this nutrients column to make each as a sub column or row?

Actually it was a JSON file and I already flattened it into this. But I couldn't go further :(

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**:
Please see below for more information and what i tried:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a sample of your JSON file in __text__ form so we could copy, paste and develop a working solution? I guess it should be possible to flatten your JSON file in the way you want it without postprocessing

Comment: I posted a detailed comment below, if you want I can send another text form of the JSON file. Thanks again!

Comment: how do you think why did i mark "in __text__ form" bold in my first comment? ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) in order to flatten your JSON file like this:

```
import ujson
import pandas as pd

with open('/path/to/your/file.json') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, 'nutrients', ['measure','name','ndbno','weight'])
```

assuming that `['measure','name','ndbno','weight']` - aren't nested

Comment: Thank you @MaxU, but it doesn't work in my case. At least I couldn't.

Comment: @MaxU. And what if 'nutrients' is nested one more time. I am facing this same issue, but my 'nutrients' column has a second level and using (data, ['nutrients', 'something_else']) is not working.

Comment: @DanielVargas, please ask (open) a question and post there your data set (JSON) in text form and your desired data set

Comment: @MaxU i have actually done it several times. Please see one of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319424/digging-down-json-file

Comment: @MaxU I updated this question, and it is a lot more clear with a full chunck of the file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242845/pandas-io-json-json-normalize-with-very-nested-json

Comment: @DanielVargas, that question already has an accepted answer - don't change it, open a new one or change one where you didn't have any answers

Comment: Ok. Will do. Thanks

Comment: @MaxU https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341519/json-normalize-for-dicts-within-dicts