# pandas json_normalize with very nested json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, json-normalize

I have been trying to `normalize` a very nested json file I will later analyze. What I am struggling with is how to go more than one level deep to normalize.

I went through the [pandas.io.json.json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) documentation, since it does exactly what I want it to do.

I have been able to normalize part of it and now understand how dictionaries work, but I am still not there.

With below code I am able to get only the first level.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('authors_sample.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

raw = json_normalize(d['hits']['hits'])

authors = json_normalize(data=d['hits']['hits'], 
                         record_path='_source', 
                         meta=['_id',
                               ['_source', 'journal'],
                               ['_source', 'title'], 
                               ['_source', 'normalized_venue_name']
                              ])
```

I am trying to 'dig' into the 'authors' dictionary with below code, but the `record_path = ['_source', 'authors']` throws me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. As far as I understand `json_normalize` the logic should be good, but I still don't quite understand how to dive into a json with `dict` vs `list`.

I even went through this simple [example](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas/notebook).

```
authors = json_normalize(data=d['hits']['hits'], 
                         record_path=['_source', 'authors'], 
                         meta=['_id',
                               ['_source', 'journal'],
                               ['_source', 'title'], 
                               ['_source', 'normalized_venue_name']
                              ])
```

Below is a chunk of the json file (5 records).

```
{u'_shards': {u'failed': 0, u'successful': 5, u'total': 5},
 u'hits': {u'hits': [{u'_id': u'7CB3F2AD',
    u'_index': u'scibase_listings',
    u'_score': 1.0,
    u'_source': {u'authors': None,
     u'deleted': 0,
     u'description': None,
     u'doi': u'',
     u'is_valid': 1,
     u'issue': None,
     u'journal': u'Physical Review Letters',
     u'link': None,
     u'meta_description': None,
     u'meta_keywords': None,
     u'normalized_venue_name': u'phys rev lett',
     u'pages': None,
     u'parent_keywords': [u'Chromatography',
      u'Quantum mechanics',
      u'Particle physics',
      u'Quantum field theory',
      u'Analytical chemistry',
      u'Quantum chromodynamics',
      u'Physics',
      u'Mass spectrometry',
      u'Chemistry'],
     u'pub_date': u'1987-03-02 00:00:00',
     u'pubtype': None,
     u'rating_avg_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_clarity': 0.0,
     u'rating_clarity_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_num_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_reproducability': 0,
     u'rating_reproducibility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'review_count': 0,
     u'tag': [u'mass spectra', u'elementary particles', u'bound states'],
     u'title': u'Evidence for a new meson: A quasinuclear NN-bar bound state',
     u'userAvg': 0.0,
     u'user_id': None,
     u'venue_name': u'Physical Review Letters',
     u'views_count': 0,
     u'volume': None},
    u'_type': u'listing'},
   {u'_id': u'7AF8EBC3',
    u'_index': u'scibase_listings',
    u'_score': 1.0,
    u'_source': {u'authors': [{u'affiliations': [u'Punjabi University'],
       u'author_id': u'780E3459',
       u'author_name': u'munish puri'},
      {u'affiliations': [u'Punjabi University'],
       u'author_id': u'48D92C79',
       u'author_name': u'rajesh dhaliwal'},
      {u'affiliations': [u'Punjabi University'],
       u'author_id': u'7D9BD37C',
       u'author_name': u'r s singh'}],
     u'deleted': 0,
     u'description': None,
     u'doi': u'',
     u'is_valid': 1,
     u'issue': None,
     u'journal': u'Journal of Industrial Microbiology & Biotechnology',
     u'link': None,
     u'meta_description': None,
     u'meta_keywords': None,
     u'normalized_venue_name': u'j ind microbiol biotechnol',
     u'pages': None,
     u'parent_keywords': [u'Nuclear medicine',
      u'Psychology',
      u'Hydrology',
      u'Chromatography',
      u'X-ray crystallography',
      u'Nuclear fusion',
      u'Medicine',
      u'Fluid dynamics',
      u'Thermodynamics',
      u'Physics',
      u'Gas chromatography',
      u'Radiobiology',
      u'Engineering',
      u'Organic chemistry',
      u'High-performance liquid chromatography',
      u'Chemistry',
      u'Organic synthesis',
      u'Psychotherapist'],
     u'pub_date': u'2008-04-04 00:00:00',
     u'pubtype': None,
     u'rating_avg_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_clarity': 0.0,
     u'rating_clarity_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_num_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_reproducability': 0,
     u'rating_reproducibility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'review_count': 0,
     u'tag': [u'flow rate',
      u'operant conditioning',
      u'packed bed reactor',
      u'immobilized enzyme',
      u'specific activity'],
     u'title': u'Development of a stable continuous flow immobilized enzyme reactor for the hydrolysis of inulin',
     u'userAvg': 0.0,
     u'user_id': None,
     u'venue_name': u'Journal of Industrial Microbiology & Biotechnology',
     u'views_count': 0,
     u'volume': None},
    u'_type': u'listing'},
   {u'_id': u'7521A721',
    u'_index': u'scibase_listings',
    u'_score': 1.0,
    u'_source': {u'authors': [{u'author_id': u'7FF872BC',
       u'author_name': u'barbara eileen ryan'}],
     u'deleted': 0,
     u'description': None,
     u'doi': u'',
     u'is_valid': 1,
     u'issue': None,
     u'journal': u'The American Historical Review',
     u'link': None,
     u'meta_description': None,
     u'meta_keywords': None,
     u'normalized_venue_name': u'american historical review',
     u'pages': None,
     u'parent_keywords': [u'Social science',
      u'Politics',
      u'Sociology',
      u'Law'],
     u'pub_date': u'1992-01-01 00:00:00',
     u'pubtype': None,
     u'rating_avg_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_clarity': 0.0,
     u'rating_clarity_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_num_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_reproducability': 0,
     u'rating_reproducibility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'review_count': 0,
     u'tag': [u'social movements'],
     u'title': u"Feminism and the women's movement : dynamics of change in social movement ideology, and activism",
     u'userAvg': 0.0,
     u'user_id': None,
     u'venue_name': u'The American Historical Review',
     u'views_count': 0,
     u'volume': None},
    u'_type': u'listing'},
   {u'_id': u'7DAEB9A4',
    u'_index': u'scibase_listings',
    u'_score': 1.0,
    u'_source': {u'authors': [{u'author_id': u'0299B8E9',
       u'author_name': u'fraser j harbutt'}],
     u'deleted': 0,
     u'description': None,
     u'doi': u'',
     u'is_valid': 1,
     u'issue': None,
     u'journal': u'The American Historical Review',
     u'link': None,
     u'meta_description': None,
     u'meta_keywords': None,
     u'normalized_venue_name': u'american historical review',
     u'pages': None,
     u'parent_keywords': [u'Superconductivity',
      u'Nuclear fusion',
      u'Geology',
      u'Chemistry',
      u'Metallurgy'],
     u'pub_date': u'1988-01-01 00:00:00',
     u'pubtype': None,
     u'rating_avg_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_clarity': 0.0,
     u'rating_clarity_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_num_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_reproducability': 0,
     u'rating_reproducibility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'review_count': 0,
     u'tag': [u'iron'],
     u'title': u'The iron curtain : Churchill, America, and the origins of the Cold War',
     u'userAvg': 0.0,
     u'user_id': None,
     u'venue_name': u'The American Historical Review',
     u'views_count': 0,
     u'volume': None},
    u'_type': u'listing'},
   {u'_id': u'7B3236C5',
    u'_index': u'scibase_listings',
    u'_score': 1.0,
    u'_source': {u'authors': [{u'author_id': u'7DAB7B72',
       u'author_name': u'richard m freeland'}],
     u'deleted': 0,
     u'description': None,
     u'doi': u'',
     u'is_valid': 1,
     u'issue': None,
     u'journal': u'The American Historical Review',
     u'link': None,
     u'meta_description': None,
     u'meta_keywords': None,
     u'normalized_venue_name': u'american historical review',
     u'pages': None,
     u'parent_keywords': [u'Political Science', u'Economics'],
     u'pub_date': u'1985-01-01 00:00:00',
     u'pubtype': None,
     u'rating_avg_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_clarity': 0.0,
     u'rating_clarity_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation': 0.0,
     u'rating_innovation_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_num_weighted': 0,
     u'rating_reproducability': 0,
     u'rating_reproducibility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility': 0.0,
     u'rating_versatility_weighted': 0.0,
     u'review_count': 0,
     u'tag': [u'foreign policy'],
     u'title': u'The Truman Doctrine and the origins of McCarthyism : foreign policy, domestic politics, and internal security, 1946-1948',
     u'userAvg': 0.0,
     u'user_id': None,
     u'venue_name': u'The American Historical Review',
     u'views_count': 0,
     u'volume': None},
    u'_type': u'listing'}],
  u'max_score': 1.0,
  u'total': 36429433},
 u'timed_out': False,
 u'took': 170}
```

Comment: You may be able to handle this directly from your opensearch/elasticsearch query. Alternatively you can preprocess it with python and then load it into pandas - that's what we do.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> In the pandas example (below) what do the brackets mean? Is there a logic to be followed to go deeper with the []. *[...]*
>
> ```
> result = json_normalize(data, 'counties', ['state', 'shortname', ['info', 'governor']])
> ```

Each string or list of strings in the `['state', 'shortname', ['info', 'governor']]` value is a path to an element to include, *in addition to the selected rows*. The second argument `json_normalize()` argument (`record_path`, set to `'counties'` in the documentation example) tells the function how to select elements from the input data structure that make up the rows in the output, and the `meta` paths adds further metadata that will be included with each of the rows. Think of these as table joins in a database, if you will.

The input for [the *US States* documentation example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) has two dictionaries in a list, and both of these dictionaries have a `counties` key that references another list of dicts:

```
>>> data = [{'state': 'Florida',
...          'shortname': 'FL',
...         'info': {'governor': 'Rick Scott'},
...         'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
...                      {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
...                      {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
...         {'state': 'Ohio',
...          'shortname': 'OH',
...          'info': {'governor': 'John Kasich'},
...          'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
...                       {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]}]
>>> pprint(data[0]['counties'])
[{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
 {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
 {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]
>>> pprint(data[1]['counties'])
[{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
 {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]
```

Between them there are 5 rows of data to use in the output:

```
>>> json_normalize(data, 'counties')
         name  population
0        Dade       12345
1     Broward       40000
2  Palm Beach       60000
3      Summit        1234
4    Cuyahoga        1337
```

The `meta` argument then names some elements that live *next* to those `counties` lists, and those are then merged in separately. The values from the first `data[0]` dictionary for those `meta` elements are `('Florida', 'FL', 'Rick Scott')`, respectively, and for `data[1]` the values are `('Ohio', 'OH', 'John Kasich')`, so you see those values attached to the `counties` rows that came from the same top-level dictionary, repeated 3 and 2 times respectively:

```
>>> data[0]['state'], data[0]['shortname'], data[0]['info']['governor']
('Florida', 'FL', 'Rick Scott')
>>> data[1]['state'], data[1]['shortname'], data[1]['info']['governor']
('Ohio', 'OH', 'John Kasich')
>>> json_normalize(data, 'counties', ['state', 'shortname', ['info', 'governor']])
         name  population    state shortname info.governor
0        Dade       12345  Florida        FL    Rick Scott
1     Broward       40000  Florida        FL    Rick Scott
2  Palm Beach       60000  Florida        FL    Rick Scott
3      Summit        1234     Ohio        OH   John Kasich
4    Cuyahoga        1337     Ohio        OH   John Kasich
```

So, if you pass in a list for the `meta` argument, then each element in the list is a separate path, and each of those separate paths identifies data to add to the rows in the output.

In *your* example JSON, there are only a few nested lists to elevate with the first argument, like `'counties'` did in the example. The only example in that datastructure is the nested `'authors'` key; you'd have to extract each `['_source', 'authors']` path, after which you can add other keys from the parent object to augment those rows.

The second `meta` argument then pulls in the `_id` key from the outermost objects, followed by the nested `['_source', 'title']` and `['_source', 'journal']` nested paths.

The `record_path` argument takes the `authors` lists as the starting point, these look like:

```
>>> d['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['authors']   # this value is None, and is skipped
>>> d['hits']['hits'][1]['_source']['authors']
[{'affiliations': ['Punjabi University'],
  'author_id': '780E3459',
  'author_name': 'munish puri'},
 {'affiliations': ['Punjabi University'],
  'author_id': '48D92C79',
  'author_name': 'rajesh dhaliwal'},
 {'affiliations': ['Punjabi University'],
  'author_id': '7D9BD37C',
  'author_name': 'r s singh'}]
>>> d['hits']['hits'][2]['_source']['authors']
[{'author_id': '7FF872BC',
  'author_name': 'barbara eileen ryan'}]
>>> # etc.
```

and so gives you the following rows:

```
>>> json_normalize(d['hits']['hits'], ['_source', 'authors'])
           affiliations author_id          author_name
0  [Punjabi University]  780E3459          munish puri
1  [Punjabi University]  48D92C79      rajesh dhaliwal
2  [Punjabi University]  7D9BD37C            r s singh
3                   NaN  7FF872BC  barbara eileen ryan
4                   NaN  0299B8E9     fraser j harbutt
5                   NaN  7DAB7B72   richard m freeland
```

and then we can use the third `meta` argument to add more columns like `_id`, `_source.title` and `_source.journal`, using `['_id', ['_source', 'journal'], ['_source', 'title']]`:

```
>>> json_normalize(
...     data['hits']['hits'],
...     ['_source', 'authors'],
...     ['_id', ['_source', 'journal'], ['_source', 'title']]
... )
           affiliations author_id          author_name       _id   \
0  [Punjabi University]  780E3459          munish puri  7AF8EBC3  
1  [Punjabi University]  48D92C79      rajesh dhaliwal  7AF8EBC3
2  [Punjabi University]  7D9BD37C            r s singh  7AF8EBC3
3                   NaN  7FF872BC  barbara eileen ryan  7521A721
4                   NaN  0299B8E9     fraser j harbutt  7DAEB9A4
5                   NaN  7DAB7B72   richard m freeland  7B3236C5

                                     _source.journal
0  Journal of Industrial Microbiology & Biotechno...
1  Journal of Industrial Microbiology & Biotechno...
2  Journal of Industrial Microbiology & Biotechno...
3                     The American Historical Review
4                     The American Historical Review
5                     The American Historical Review

                                       _source.title  \
0  Development of a stable continuous flow immobi...
1  Development of a stable continuous flow immobi...
2  Development of a stable continuous flow immobi...
3  Feminism and the women's movement : dynamics o...
4  The iron curtain : Churchill, America, and the...
5  The Truman Doctrine and the origins of McCarth...
```

Comment: This answer is somehow difficult for me to understand. I wish the language were clearer.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader: I've updated my answer, hopefully it's a little clearer now than it was before.

Comment: I wish you added the data to your answer so that it is much easier to follow. Still, this is the best explanation about json_normalize. Link to the aforementioned data example https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: @iRestMyCaseYourHonor: the data used to be part of the question, it's unfortunate that it was changed so much in that respect. I've added a reference and the dictionary to my answer now.

Answer (score 25):

You can also have a look at the library **flatten_json**, which does not require you to write column hierarchies as in json_normalize:

```
from flatten_json import flatten

data = d['hits']['hits']
dict_flattened = (flatten(record, '.') for record in data)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_flattened)
print(df)
```

See https://github.com/amirziai/flatten.

Comment: thank you for this solution. this helped me minimize lot of code i wrote using pandas normalize function

Comment: Thank you for this! Didn't know about the flatten_json library before. This will minimize my code by quite a bit.

Comment: Any idea on how this performs compared to json_normalize?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Sanders comment,
more context can be found here as the creator of this function has a medium blog:
https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10

It is worth keeping in mind that panda's json_normalize can handle most json objects, like arrays for example. The flatten_json library requires it to be a nested dict. However, you can work around this requirement by adding the array to a dict like so:

```
flatten({'response':data}, '.')
```

In this case, the flatten_json library will actually use a counter in the dot notation to distinguished against duplicates. For example:

```
flatten({
    'response': [
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '0', 'cost_micros': '0', 'impressions': '3'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-01'}},
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '1', 'cost_micros': '609240', 'impressions': '358'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-01'}},
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '0', 'cost_micros': '0', 'impressions': '3'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-02'}},
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '2', 'cost_micros': '40000', 'impressions': '291'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-02'}},
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '0', 'cost_micros': '0', 'impressions': '2'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-03'}},
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '2', 'cost_micros': '337754', 'impressions': '241'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-03'}},
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '0', 'cost_micros': '0', 'impressions': '4'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-04'}},
        {'metrics': {'clicks': '2', 'cost_micros': '757299', 'impressions': '197'},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-12-04'}}
    ]
}, '.')
```

Produces:

```
{'response.0.metrics.clicks': '0',
 'response.0.metrics.cost_micros': '0',
 'response.0.metrics.impressions': '3',
 'response.0.segments.date': '2022-12-01',
 'response.1.metrics.clicks': '1',
 'response.1.metrics.cost_micros': '609240',
 'response.1.metrics.impressions': '358',
 'response.1.segments.date': '2022-12-01',
 'response.2.metrics.clicks': '0',
 'response.2.metrics.cost_micros': '0',
 'response.2.metrics.impressions': '3',
 'response.2.segments.date': '2022-12-02',
 'response.3.metrics.clicks': '2',
 'response.3.metrics.cost_micros': '40000',
 'response.3.metrics.impressions': '291',
 'response.3.segments.date': '2022-12-02',
 'response.4.metrics.clicks': '0',
 'response.4.metrics.cost_micros': '0',
 'response.4.metrics.impressions': '2',
 'response.4.segments.date': '2022-12-03',
 'response.5.metrics.clicks': '2',
 'response.5.metrics.cost_micros': '337754',
 'response.5.metrics.impressions': '241',
 'response.5.segments.date': '2022-12-03',
 'response.6.metrics.clicks': '0',
 'response.6.metrics.cost_micros': '0',
 'response.6.metrics.impressions': '4',
 'response.6.segments.date': '2022-12-04',
 'response.7.metrics.clicks': '2',
 'response.7.metrics.cost_micros': '757299',
 'response.7.metrics.impressions': '197',
 'response.7.segments.date': '2022-12-04'}
```