# Reading nested JSON file in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, tweets

I have a JSON file with the following structure (it's not the complete json file, but the structure is the same):

```
{"data":[{"referenced_tweets":[{"type":"retweeted","id":"xxxxxxx"}],"text":"abcdefghijkl","created_at":"2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z","author_id":"xxxxx","id":"xxxxxxxxxxx"},{"referenced_tweets":[{"type":"retweeted","id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}],"text":"abcdefghijkl","created_at":"2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z","author_id":"xxxxxxxx","id":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}]}
..... 

//The rest of json continues with the same structure, but referenced_tweets is not always present
```

**My question:** How can I load this data into a dataframe with these columns: `type`, `id(referenced_tweet id)`, `text`, `created_at`, `author_id`, and `id (tweet id)`?

**What I could do so far:** I could get the following columns:

| referenced_tweets | text | cerated_at | author_id | id (tweet id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [{'type': 'xx', 'id': 'xxx'}] | xxx | xxxx | xxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxx |

Here is the code to get the above table:

```
with open('Test_SampleRetweets.json') as json_file:
    data_list = json.load(json_file)

df1 = json_normalize(data_list, 'data')
df1.head()
```

However, I'd like to get the `type` and `id` (in referenced_tweets) in separate columns and I could get the following so far:

| type | id (referenced_tweet id) |
| --- | --- |
| xxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |

and here is the code to get the above table:

```
df2 = json_normalize(data_list, record_path=['data','referenced_tweets'], errors='ignore')
df2.head()
```

**What is the problem?** I'd like to get everything in one table, i.e., a table similar to the first one here but with `type` and `id` in separate columns (like the 2nd table). So, the final columns should be : `type`, `id (referenced_tweet id)`, `text`, `created_at`, `author_id`, and `id (tweet id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


with open('Test_SampleRetweets.json') as json_file:
    raw_data = json.load(json_file)


data = []
for item in raw_data["data"]:
    item["tweet_id"] = item["id"]
    item.update(item["referenced_tweets"][0])
    del item["referenced_tweets"]
    data.append(item)


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1.head())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code almost gives me the columns I need. I just don't know why the `id (tweet id)` column is missing. Do you have any idea?

Comment: There should be two `id` columns. One id refers to referenced_tweet id and the other one (the missing one) is tweet id

Comment: @mOna ah sorry, I see, sec, i will update my answer

Comment: @mOna it was fixed

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could I ask why only `id` was missing? I mean all other columns (e.g., author_id, conversation_id) were present

Comment: Sorry, I just have one more question. Could I ask what does `[0]`.. in `item.update(item["referenced_tweets"][0])` means? and why you used [0]?

Comment: @mOna, sure, because in your original structure value of "referenced_tweets" isn't a dict, but a list with one element (this dict), therefore we need to use access by index 0 in this list

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

when working with a nested json in `json_normalize()`, you need to work with the `meta` parameter to get the fields in the meta level. So, essentially what you are doing is taking the nested and normalizing it and than left joining several other field from a level above. Apparently, you can combine this for several nested fields, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242845/pandas-io-json-json-normalize-with-very-nested-json) for reference.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

j = '{"data":[{"referenced_tweets":[{"type":"retweeted","id":"xxxxxxx"}],"text":"abcdefghijkl","created_at":"2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z","author_id":"xxxxx","id":"xxxxxxxxxxx"},{"referenced_tweets":[{"type":"retweeted","id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}],"text":"abcdefghijkl","created_at":"2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z","author_id":"xxxxxxxx","id":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}]}'
j = json.loads(j)

# since you have id twice, it's a bit more complicated and you need to 
# introduce a meta prefix
df = pd.json_normalize(
    j,
    record_path=["data", 'referenced_tweets'],
    meta_prefix="data.",
    meta=[["data", "text"], ["data", "created_at"], ["data", "author_id"], ["data", "id"]]
    )
print(df)
```

resulting in:

```
        type            id data.data.text      data.data.created_at  \
0  retweeted       xxxxxxx   abcdefghijkl  2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z   
1  retweeted  xxxxxxxxxxxx   abcdefghijkl  2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z   

  data.data.author_id data.data.id  
0               xxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxx  
1            xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxx
```

I would prefere it this way, since it seems simpler to handle

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    j["data"],
    record_path=['referenced_tweets'],
    meta_prefix="data.",
    meta=["text", "created_at", "author_id", "id"]
    )
print(df)
```

resulting in:

```
        type            id     data.text           data.created_at  \
0  retweeted       xxxxxxx  abcdefghijkl  2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z   
1  retweeted  xxxxxxxxxxxx  abcdefghijkl  2020-03-09T00:11:41.000Z   

  data.author_id      data.id  
0          xxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxx  
1       xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: I get this error when I run your code: `module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'`. I imported the following too: `import json`, 
`from pandas.io.json import json_normalize` and
`import pandas as pd`

Comment: you could update pandas, you are probably using something before v.1.2.3. `json_normalize` was in io tools before that version. You may get a future waring now when using `pandas.io.json`