# Digging down json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have been trying in many ways (and by many questions in stackoverflow) to normalize a deep json file.
I have tried with `.apply(pd.Series)`, not great with many levels of dictionary.

I am currently trying with `json_normalize` and it has given some results. I think I know how the function works and that my problem is that I don't know how to navigate through a dictionary.

So far, I have been able to dig into 2 levels.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
raw = json.load(open('authors.json'))
raw2 = json_normalize(raw['hits']['hits'])
```

And it gives me what I need (at least the first levels). But I don't know how to go deeper.

I've tried:

```
raw2 = json_normalize(raw['hits']['hits'][0])
raw2 = json_normalize(raw['hits']['hits']['_source.authors'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And many more, but just randomly trying stuff without understanding is not the right way. I guess my questions are:

- How do I know how to include the next level (`{}` vs `[]` in the json)?
- Is there any visual way to represent this?

It is weird that this topic is not developed more online. Day by day I work more and more with `json` data.

```
_id _index  _score  _source.authors _source.deleted _source.description _source.doi _source.is_valid    _source.issue   _source.journal ... _source.rating_versatility_weighted _source.review_count    _source.tag _source.title   _source.userAvg _source.user_id _source.venue_name  _source.views_count _source.volume  _type   
0   7CB3F2AD    scibase_listings    1   None    0   None        1   None    Physical Review Letters ... 0   0   [mass spectra, elementary particles, bound sta...   Evidence for a new meson: A quasinuclear NN-ba...   0   None    Physical Review Letters 0   None    listing
1   7AF8EBC3    scibase_listings    1   [{'affiliations': ['Punjabi University'], 'aut...   0   None        1   None    Journal of Industrial Microbiology & Biotechno...   ... 0   0   [flow rate, operant conditioning, packed bed r...   Development of a stable continuous flow immobi...   0   None    Journal of Industrial Microbiology & Biotechno...   0   None    listing
2   7521A721    scibase_listings    1   [{'author_id': '7FF872BC', 'author_name': 'bar...   0   None        1   None    The American Historical Review  ... 0   0   [social movements]  Feminism and the women's movement : dynamics o...   0   None    The American Historical Review  0   None    listing
```

This is a chunk of the file (this is level 3, level 1 and 2 are, hits, hits).

```
{
"_shards": {
    "failed": 0,
    "successful": 5,
    "total": 5
},
"hits": {
    "hits": [{
            "_id": "7CB3F2AD",
            "_index": "scibase_listings",
            "_type": "listing",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "userAvg": 0,
                "meta_keywords": null,
                "views_count": 0,
                "rating_reproducability": 0,
                "rating_versatility": 0,
                "rating_innovation": 0,
                "tag": null,
                "rating_reproducibility_weighted": 0,
                "meta_description": null,
                "review_count": 0,
                "rating_avg_weighted": 0,
                "venue_name": "The American Historical Review",
                "rating_num_weighted": 0,
                "is_valid": 1,
                "normalized_venue_name": "american historical review",
                "rating_clarity": 0,
                "description": null,
                "deleted": 0,
                "journal": "The American Historical Review",
                "volume": null,
                "link": null,
                "authors": [{
                        "author_id": "166468F4",
                        "author_name": "a bowdoin van riper"
                    },
                    {
                        "author_id": "81070854",
                        "author_name": "jeffrey h schwartz"
                    }
                ],
                "user_id": null,
                "pub_date": "1994-01-01 00:00:00",
                "pages": null,
                "doi": "",
                "issue": null,
                "rating_versatility_weighted": 0,
                "pubtype": null,
                "title": "Men Among the Mammoths: Victorian Science and the Discovery of Human Prehistory",
                "rating_clarity_weighted": 0,
                "rating_innovation_weighted": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "scibase_listings",
            "_type": "listing",
            "_id": "7538108B",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "userAvg": 0,
                "meta_keywords": null,
                "views_count": 0,
                "rating_reproducability": 0,
                "rating_versatility": 0,
                "rating_innovation": 0,
                "tag": null,
                "rating_reproducibility_weighted": 0,
                "meta_description": null,
                "review_count": 0,
                "rating_avg_weighted": 0,
                "venue_name": "The American Historical Review",
                "rating_num_weighted": 0,
                "is_valid": 1,
                "normalized_venue_name": "american historical review",
                "rating_clarity": 0,
                "description": null,
                "deleted": 0,
                "journal": "The American Historical Review",
                "volume": null,
                "link": null,
                "authors": [{
                    "affiliations": [
                        "Pennsylvania State University"
                    ],
                    "author_id": "7E15BDFA",
                    "author_name": "roger l geiger"
                }],
                "user_id": null,
                "pub_date": "2013-06-01 00:00:00",
                "pages": null,
                "doi": "10.1093/ahr/118.3.896a",
                "issue": null,
                "rating_versatility_weighted": 0,
                "pubtype": null,
                "title": "Elizabeth Popp Berman. Creating the Market University: How Academic Science Became an Economic Engine.",
                "rating_clarity_weighted": 0,
                "rating_innovation_weighted": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: would you mind to specify a __valid__ JSON string/file, that could be parsed? Try to copy it from your question and pass it to `json.loads(json_string)` Another helpful resource is: https://jsonlint.com/ - it validates JSON files online

Comment: That one doesnt work? Is a chunk of the original one.

Comment: I have changed the invalid json to a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured out how to 'dig' through a json. It will depend if the next level is a list or a dict.

In my case I was able to dig until the end with below. I still need to find out how to use the full list (maybe loop) so I can have all values and not just `[0]` or `[1]`.

```
raw['hits']['hits'][1]['_source']['authors'][0]['affiliations']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
json_normalize(raw['hits'],'hits','_source','authors','affiliations')
```